# Why does my horse keep falling?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ok, so I recently got Skyrim SE for the PS4.  I have played Skyrim on my PS3 before.  Anyway, on the PS3 version, you can fast travel to the College of Winterhold while on a horse, and it will put your horse (and you on it) on the bridge, near the front gate.  However, when I try to do this on my PS4 version, it puts me on my horse up in the air to the side of the bridge (about 10 feet above the bridge and to the right), and my horse falls to the ground beside the sea below the bridge.  My horse dies and I fall off of it, but I am barely hurt.  I have lost 19000 gold because my horses kept dying when I would fast travel there, but it wasn't every time.  Now, I no longer fast travel there, but it is really annoying because I don't have a house to put stuff in, so when I'm overburdened I go to the College to drop off stuff in the wardrobes there.  I have to fast travel (on my horse, of course) to the actual town of Winterhold, then slowly walk to the college.  Why does this happen to my horse?  Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: "*Why does my horse keep falling?*" Because that's what they do best

Comment: Do you happen to have any mods enabled? You may have a mod causing that if you do have some mods enabled.

Comment: Cant you just fast travel to the town right next to the college of winterhold instead? - edit: typed this as I read it.  You are able to buy a house in Whiterun fairly early in the game where you can stash your stuff. If I remember correctly it was only 5,000 gold

Comment: I do not have any mods enabled.

Comment: Have you completed the quest line in Whiterun to be able to purchase a house there?

Comment: yes, but I can't afford a house yet... I had to spend all my money to help ralis sedarys excavate a barrow in raven rock...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615805-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/61444364), it sounds like this has been a bug for years, but since I've found no evidence of a fix, it doesn't look like there has been one (yet).

> I've heard that if you're on horseback and you fast travel to the College, there can be lethal consequences for you and/or your horse.
>
> Yup, don't fast travel to the College on a horse. Sometimes you'll be fine but most times it'll load you up in the air over the chasm.

Basically, the solution is just *don't fast travel to the College of Winterhold while on horseback if you value your horse's life*.

Comment: your numbers are beast recently - keep it up :D

Comment: @ZeroStack i just wanna be the very best like no one ever was, man

Comment: well I mean you have a little bit to go before you reach @RavenDreamer status

Comment: I can confirm this, I looked on the Skyrim wiki and this has been posted as a bug to fast traveling since the original release. Perhaps the unofficial skyrim bug fix mod would fix it? Assuming it is on PS4.

Comment: @Ramirez77 yes, that would probably fix it, as would some of the other mods I have seen, but I can't afford mods, and even if I could, my PS4 for some reason won't download mods... I have tried to download some free mods, and they won't download for some reason.

Comment: I would help you more on that but I never touched console Skyrim only PC.